# Root directory folder name show up in website production?

Tags: url, web, directory

I have a developed a web app. The name of the folder is:

```
c://xampp/htdocs/myfolder
```

Whenever I test this out in xampp localhost, I get this:

```
127.0.0.1/myfolder/
```

If I upload my web app to a web host company, will it be displayed as like the following?

```
www.mysite.com/myfolder/
```

If so, how can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could save it as ROOT before publishing and it will become the root directory of your website.

Comment: ah, okay, so it is not a shared directory ? I mean like every website, there is a different root folders ?

Comment: @upvote Nope, by putting it as the root directory, the website can be accessed directly.